# Extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours as well as extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

I just start learning `Oracle SQL` and I stuck in one problem.
The situation in following. I have `MySQL` database  and I want to translate some query from `MySQL` to `Oracle SQL`
I have table `weekly_report` which contain data like `YEAR`,`WEEK`.
I need to return `TOTAL_SUM` of current week and TOTAL_SUM with current week.
For example if I have 10 `weeklyReport` which is past and this week.
I want to know current state for this week and for the past week.
When I run this MySQL query in Workbanch I get result something like this

```
TOTAL_SUM
459:30
```

`459` present `hour` and `30` present `minutes`
This is MySQL query

```
    SELECT 
                        CONCAT(
                            -- extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours
                            (SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),
                            ':', 
                            -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)
                            LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                        ) 
                        AS 
                            TOTAL_SUM FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
                        FROM 
                            ata
                        INNER JOIN 
                            weekly_report
                        ON
                            weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
                        INNER JOIN 
                            ata_articles AS ataAW 
                        ON 
                            ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id 
                        WHERE 
                            ata.ATAID = $ataId
                        AND 
                            ataAW.type = 1
                        AND
                            (weekly_report.status != 3 AND weekly_report.status != 4)
                        AND
                        (
                            weekly_report.year < (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = $weeklyReportId)
                            OR
                            (
                                weekly_report.year <= (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = $weeklyReportId)
                                AND
                                weekly_report.week <= (SELECT week FROM weekly_report WHERE id = $weeklyReportId)
                            )
                        )
                    ) AS A group by A.AtaId
```

When I modify this query and write in `Oracle SQL` I get something like this

```
                SELECT 
                    CONCAT(
                        -- extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours
                        (SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),
                        ':', 
                        -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)
                        LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) TOTAL_SUM 
                        FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    INNER JOIN 
                        weekly_report
                    ON
                        weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles ataAW 
                    ON 
                        ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id 
                    WHERE 
                        ata.ATAID = 321
                    AND 
                        ataAW.type = 1
                    AND
                        (weekly_report.status != 3 AND weekly_report.status != 4)
                    AND
                    (
                        weekly_report.year < (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 200)
                        OR
                        (
                            weekly_report.year <= (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 200)
                            AND
                            weekly_report.week <= (SELECT week FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 200)
                        )
                    )
                ) A 
                group by A.AtaId
```

Currently the sitation in table in `weekly_report` is:

```
YEAR      WEEK
 2020      12
 2020      15
 2020      12
```

The problem here is that I get error message something like

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

In this line of code

```
LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) TOTAL_SUM
```

So, I assume that part with extract hours and time is not correct written.

```
 CONCAT(
                        -- extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours
                        (SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),
                        ':', 
                        -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)
                        LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) TOTAL_SUM
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ? How can I modify this to run query success ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're misusing the `MOD` function.

Should be e.g.

```
SQL> select mod(5, 2) from dual;

  MOD(5,2)
----------
         1
```

instead of

```
SQL> select 5 mod 2 from dual;
select 5 mod 2 from dual
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL>
```

Comment: I'm referring to this line of your code: `LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) TOTAL_SUM ` which uses MOD in a wrong manner.

Comment: You mean insted of LPAD using SELECT or ... ?

Comment: **MOD** is misused, not LPAD, not SELECT, not ... **MOD**.

Comment: Ok, I get this point. But how can I be sure 100% that MOD is in wrong manner ?

Comment: Ok, how can I write then this part of code 

`LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) TOTAL_SUM`

Comment: Like this: `lpad(mod(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)), 60), 2, '0')`. But, it will **fail** as well; now I noticed that you misused SUBSTR as well. Its 2nd parameter should be numeric, representing "position", not another string.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It fail as well when I change like you said. Hmmm